# Firebase firestore document is not created properly

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with cloud firestore and for some reason, I can't create new documents(up until this point i could)

```
FirebaseFirestore db;
```

**Calling the method "createUserDoc" to create new document**

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    createUserDoc();
}
```

**The method**

```
    private void createUserDoc() {
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Map<String, Object> userDetails = new HashMap<>();
    userDetails.put("phone" , phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString());
    db.collection("users")
            .document()
            .set(userDetails)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LogingWithPhoneActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        }
    });
}
```

note - even the  [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) from the official document did not work for me suddenly

Comment: Did you receive any errors? If the official example code didn't work too, you probably have issue in your project configurations. If you write sample value to the db like "db.collections("users").document("test").set("key","value")", it works? Have you followe the "Get started" guide correctly?  Also insert a debug line in the "onFailure" to can read if there are errors.

Comment: I did insert debug line in "onFailure" and got no error at all
in addition, I got 0 errors (generally), and I think that "onComplete" is never called  (if it would then the intent would move the user to the next  screen)

Comment: If you are trying to use and if statement `if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    //
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage());
}`. What is the result in the logcat?

Comment: @AlexMamo the result in the logcat is nothing , i do not get any print at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the firebase rules were not configured correctly, after changing the rules it solved the problem.

The weird part is that were no problems and not a single error log which is weird because usually if firebase rules will prevent accessing the data there will be logs regards this.

Anyway, all I had to do was change the rules in the database.